# POST undefined index $v3

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I work with ajax in wordpress, I want to show what the user enters,
the success of ajax is sent to the server, but the POST array issues
an indefinite index in my index.php, why doesn't it work?

**inc/send.php**

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_applican', 'applican');
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_applican', 'applican');
    function applican(){
        $v3 = $_POST['v3'];
    };
    ?>
```

**/js/custom.js**

```
let arr = [];
btnNext.on('click', () => {
    if(roomsRadio.is(':checked')) {
        calc.slick('slickNext');
        arr['version1'] = $('.rooms   input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
        console.log(arr['version1'])
    }
    if(versionRadio.is(':checked')) {
        calc.slick('slickNext');
        arr['version2'] = strip_html_tags($('.version   input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
        console.log(arr['version2'])
    }
    if(typeRadio.is(':checked')) {
        calc.slick('slickNext');
        arr['version3'] = strip_html_tags($('.type input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
        console.log(arr['version3'])
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {"action": "applican", "v3": arr['version3'], "v2": arr['version2'], "v1": arr['version1']},
            success: function(msg) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log({"v3": arr['version3']});
            }
        })
    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php applican(); echo $v3; ?>
```

Comment: Variables in PHP aren't global. When you define a variable inside a function, that variable will only be available in that function. Read up on [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Magnus said, variables in PHP have different scopes [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), You can't reach it out of the scope. In your code, `$v3` can only be reached inside the function `applican()`, but not `index.php`. You can extend the variable's scope with keyword `global`:

```
<?php # inc/send.php
    function applican(){
        global $v3;
        $v3 = $_POST['v3'];
    };
```

Or other solution like:

```
<?php # inc/send.php
    function applican(){
        return $_POST['v3'];
    };

<?php # index.php
    $v3 = applican(); echo $v3;
```